# List of possible classifiers and types in dependencies

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, classification

I have searched the net for the all the possible values that you can put in the scope tag inside dependency tag, but I haven't found any list with the same data for the classiffier and the type.

Anybody knows what I can and cannot put inside this tags?

Just to be clear, I am not asking what does the classifier tag or the type tag do, I just want a list of the data that this tag accepts or where can I find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the Maven Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies):

#### Update

Oops, I misunderstood the question. Here is my second shot (important parts italicized by me):

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. *It is some optional and arbitrary string* that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.

To me this suggests that you can use any classifier you want - it is not limited to a certain set of possible values.

> **type**: Corresponds to the dependant artifact's packaging type. This defaults to `jar`. *While it usually represents the extension on the filename of the dependency, that is not always the case.* A type can be mapped to a different extension and a classifier. The type often corresponds to the packaging used, though this is also not always the case. Some examples are `jar`, `ejb-client` and `test-jar`. *New types can be defined by plugins that set extensions to true, so this is not a complete list.*

Which again tells, that although usually you won't find anything else in this property as the well known packaging types, the list of possible values is open and plugin-specific.

Comment: "To me this suggests that you can use any classifier you want - it is not limited to a certain set of possible values." That's true, but there surely are some classifiers that carry special meaning / purpose, such as 'sources', 'javadoc' etc. And it you pick something arbitrary instead, it won't have the desired effect. So it would still be nice to have a comprehensive list somewhere of all the 'special' classifier names that should be used for specific kinds of artefacts.

Answer (score 4):

- Default possible values for ***type***

  ```
  pom, jar, maven-plugin, ebb, war, ear, rar, java-source, javadoc, ejb-client, test-jar
  ```
- Default possible values for ***classifier***

  ```
  sources, javadoc, client, tests
  ```

https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html