# Does Maven's dependency type expand out to type + classifier?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management, maven-bom

Follow up question to the [List of possible classifiers and types in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124537/list-of-possible-classifiers-and-types-in-dependencies). The accepted answer points at the Maven reference guide

> **type**: Corresponds to the dependant artifact's packaging type. This
>   defaults to jar. *While it usually represents the extension on the
>   filename of the dependency, that is not always the case. A type can be
>   mapped to a different extension and a classifier.* The type often
>   corresponds to the packaging used, though this is also not always the
>   case. Some examples are jar, ejb-client and test-jar. New types can be
>   defined by plugins that set extensions to true, so this is not a
>   complete list.

In practice this means a dependency like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

corresponds to a file named my-lib-1.0.1-tests.jar.

My question is could I alternatively define the dependency as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

as that's essentially what it expands out to.

This is question for me as I'm trying to generate a bom file for a project. This means I'll create a dependencyManagement section listing all the jars (etc) that can be consumed by other projects. But to create the bom I'm

- Deploying the project to a local repo
- Parsing that directory to figure out which dependencies are produced

As a result I've only access to the expanded type and classifier.

Comment: A jar which is is `<type>test-jar</type>` is something different than a jar which is `<type>jar</type>`. http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html.

Comment: Correct - the produced jars are different. But I'd be curious to know if suppling <type>jar</jar> + <classifier>tests</classifier> is enough information for Maven to retrieve the test-jar rather than the jar. In my local testing it seems like it is. But I can't stand by that 100%.

Comment: The classifier `tests` is the default one which is used but you can't rely on it..and furthermore I wouldn't rely on behavour which is currently working in particular type: jar or type:test-jar...the type:test-jar is the correct one...so you are on the safe side....

Comment: Certainly would prefer to use type:test-jar. But working backwards from the filename towards that seems to require a lot of special rules. Which is none ideal for my solution.